# Django dumpdata django.contrib.auth

Tags: python, django, manage.py

I want dump data of `django.contrib.auth` app.

I've tried:

```
>> python manage.py dumpdata django.contrib.auth > 'django.contrib.admin.json'
Error: Unknown application: django.contrib.auth
>> python manage.py dumpdata 'django.contrib.auth' > 'django.contrib.admin.json'
Error: Unknown application: django.contrib.auth
```

Nothing works. Need your help.

Comment: Other management commands are working?

Comment: @singer, yes, `python manage.py dumpdata myapp > 'myapp.json` works fine

Comment: Are you using virtualenv? django.contrib.auth is in INSTALLED_APPS, sorry for obvious question just to check.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @singer, yes, `django.contrib.auth` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`. OS is Ubuntu

Comment: About virtualenv. I don't know for sure, but I guess I use it. I can use apps from my python dir

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Solution was much more easy than a thought. Just run

```
python manage.py dumpdata auth
```

Comment: If you want just user, you can run: `python manage.py dumpdata auth.user`